# how to add docker support for the web application developed by using .netcore and angular5?

Tags: docker, .net-core, angular5, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I developed simple web application using .NET core and Angular5 by following this [Create Angular 5 application using .NET Core 2.0 Template in Visual Studio 2017](https://neelbhatt.com/2017/12/21/create-angular-5-application-using-net-core-2-0-template-in-visual-studio-2017/). But I want to add the Docker support for that application.

So, how can I add the Docker support and how to do CI and CD using VSTS for that application.

Comment: I'd suggest asking separate questions in new forum threads. Thus, forum readers may recognize questions and answers easily.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Enable docker support: Right click the project > Add > Docker support.

Regarding CI and CD for Docker supported project in VSTS, there are some build templates, such as Container (Preview), ASP.NET with containers. You need to update it per to the detail requirement.

There is a blog that may benefit you: [Continuous Deployment for Docker with VSTS and Azure Container Registry](https://blog.siliconvalve.com/2017/10/23/continuous-deployment-for-docker-with-vsts-and-azure-container-registry/)

Comment: Starian, But right now I used the angular5T template that's why I am not getting the docket support by right click the project.

Comment: Do you install docker on your machine?

Comment: Yes, I was Installed Docker in my local machine.

Comment: What're items in Add > Docker context? Can you create a Docker supported Asp.Net core project in Visual Studio 2017?